# ssh -6 localhost/<ipv6 ip>?

Tags: networking, server, services, ipv6, localhost

I am trying to ssh to my IPv6 PC from my ISP side but I could not reach. So I tried it in my IPv6 PC as

```
# ssh -6 localhost
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost: No address associated with hostname
```

And tried with link local address also.

```
# ssh -6 fe80::2ab2:bdff:fe81:929b
ssh: connect to host fe80::2ab2:bdff:fe81:929b port 22: Invalid argument
```

But I could not reach it via IPv6. So Is there any way to install ssh for IPv6.

Same result for ftp and Telnet.

My Ubuntu is 16.04.

Comment: In addition IPv6 support has improved *significantly* in the previous few years. If you depend on IPv6, do upgrade.

Comment: Ok I understand that 12.04 is older one. But how about 16.04 LTS I am observing the same from Ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone know the answer for  16.04 LTS?